# "Error: No valid response from any peers" when executing composer network install on custom fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm currently setting up a custom Hyperledger Fabric network for a Hyperledger Composer project I'm working on.

The Composer files are already okay and runs perfectly using the out of the box dev fabric server provided, i.e. `./startFabric.sh`. I have followed the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) on how to deploy an existing business network to a multi-org situation, using the given `byfn.sh`, and the network was successfully installed (`composer network install ...` successfully installs the `.bna` on the fabric network).

Now I tried to modify `byfn.sh` to support 3 (three) organizations, with only one peer for each org. The other files ([`crypto-config.yaml`](https://pastebin.com/T28SiTqd), [`configtx.yaml`](https://pastebin.com/KjR2HVG1), [`scripts/script.sh`](https://pastebin.com/Jx12rBQC), and the docker compose files) are also modified accordingly.

The e2e test in `script/script.sh` in fact runs successfully (until the "END" ASCII art appears), which lead me to think that the fabric network is set up successfully. The `docker ps` command also [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEiyX.jpg) that the docker containers are running.

However, when I'm trying to execute `composer network install` on the setup fabric, it outputs the following:

```sh
$ composer network install -c PeerAdmin@example-org1 -a stockchainz.bna
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed
```

**Why does this error appear, even though the end-to-end test runs fine?** My suspicion is that the [connection.json file](https://pastebin.com/px5ZsZEd) is somehow misconfigured, since the e2e runs perfectly fine (The "`INSERT_..._CA_CERT`" and `"INSERT_ORG_NAME"` is already replaced with the correct values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the logs, I found out that the grpc cannot find the peer. Turns out it was a certificate issue, and that my suspicion was correct. Setting `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` shows the logs when re-executing `composer network install`:

```
...
D0507 12:21:21.934229064   14853 security_handshaker.cc:127] Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1557231681.934207000","description":"Peer name localhost is not in peer certificate","file":"../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/security_connector.cc","file_line":780}
...
```

The `connection.json` sets all of the peers' url as `grpcs://localhost:<port>`. Instead of having this:

```
...
"peer0.org1.example.com": {
    "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
    "tlsCACerts" : {
        "pem": "INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT"
    }
},
...
```

I changed it to this:

```
...
"peer0.org1.example.com": {
    "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
    "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
     },
    "tlsCACerts" : {
        "pem": "INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT"
    }
},
...
```

After doing so, the business network archive is successfully installed:

```
$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@example-org1 --archiveFile business-net.bna
⠋ Installing business network. This may take a minute...D0507 12:45:04.640298851   15321 dns_resolver.cc:331]        Using native dns resolver
E0507 12:45:04.640363346   15321 trace.cc:57]                Unknown trace var: 'transport_security'
⠸ Installing business network. This may take a minute...I0507 12:45:07.172482196   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2c208d0 for subchannel 0x2b83880
I0507 12:45:07.173478121   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2b10fa0 for subchannel 0x2b572f0
I0507 12:45:07.174495644   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2c0b0e0 for subchannel 0x2b5bbe0
I0507 12:45:07.176448759   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2bac9c0 for subchannel 0x2b17bc0
⠼ Installing business network. This may take a minute...I0507 12:45:07.205505423   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2d6d400 for subchannel 0x2d65330
I0507 12:45:07.206441632   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2c21970 for subchannel 0x2d69b80
⠧ Installing business network. This may take a minute...I0507 12:45:08.365612394   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2c8efa0 for subchannel 0x2b37020
I0507 12:45:08.369911016   15321 subchannel.cc:605]          New connected subchannel at 0x2bb2660 for subchannel 0x2c9d510
✔ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Successfully installed business network business-net, version 0.1.0

Command succeeded
```